# Assigning a lap count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that contains data about various events at various times, the latter identified as seconds and milliseconds since start. I have a separate pandas `Series`, which contains the ends of laps - so e.g. the first number is the end of the first lap, the second the end of the second lap, and so on.

I would like to create a column in the `DataFrame` that, based on where the timestamp of a given event falls, identifies in which lap the event took place. Is there a way other than a simple bruteforce search for this?

Comment: Some data set snippets would be helpful if you're looking for a solution with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your lap Series be indexed by start or end time, with the value of the Series being the lap number.

Then you can use asof() to get the lap number for a series of times: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asof.html